# Генетика и гений.

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Существует ли связь между словами: ген, генетика и гений?

Answer (score 3):

ГЕНИЙ

Гениальных людей не так много, но вот гений, согласно римской мифологии,  есть в каждом человеке, а возможно,  даже в каждой вещи и   в  идеальном понятии. Вот и Пушкин писал  - «гений чистой красоты». Потому что гений – это дух-покровитель, который рождается  вместе человеком: geno (лат.) – рождаю,  genius -  рожденный дух.

Именно этот момент и связывает понятия «гений и генетика». В  какой мере он понятен?  Возможно, это душа, рожденная на земле.

Римляне считали, что дух-покровитель руководит всеми действиями человека, причем иногда дух представлялся двумя началами: добрый гений и злой гений.

Можно предположить, что дух гениального человека  проявляет особую активность, которой нет у обычных людей. Гениальность  видится как высшая степень творческой одаренности, но при этом гениальный человек творит на грани интуиции и собственной фантазии,  Платон называл такое состояние «творческим безумием».

В Европе о гениальности стали активно рассуждать с 16 века, а в русский язык слово пришло в середине 18 века в форме «гениус», но уже в 1799 году (вместе с нашим великим поэтом)  в словаре появляется «гений», а в 1834 году – «гениальный».

ГЕНЕТИКА

А в начале 20 века рождается наука генетика, имя которой  дал английский биолог Бетсон: от genos – род, genetikos – относяшийся к происхождению.
Примечание.  Есть еще одно известное слово с тем же корнем – «генеральный», от generalis – главный, общий, родовой.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, ответ на который даёт Гуглер...
Гениа́льность (от лат. genius — дух) - производим того самого гения.
Ген (др.-греч. γένος — род).
Генетика, как нетрудно догадаться из суффикса (да простят меня всезнающие, ежи ошибаюсь) - производное слово.

Answer (score 1):

Генетика, гений, джин, генеалогия, гинекология, гениталии, генерация и т.д. - происходят от санскритского (арийского) слова "джа" - рождать.

Comment: Не стану отрицать семантическую связь между "джа" и "ген", но вглядываясь и вслушиваясь в эти два набора букв и звуков, склоняюсь к тому, что в наш язык слова, о которых я спрашивал, всё же перекочевали из Рима. Возможно, именно латы так трансформировали санскритское "джа" силой горловых особенностей этой нации, что оно стало "геном".

Answer (score 0):

Имя *Евгений* означает *благородный*.
 *Гений* по-русски *родомысл*.

Кстати, *женщина* того де корня. Все женщины гении и генералы, потому что рождают.)))

Answer (score 0):

Да, связаны. "Ген" — это "род" или "предок". "Гениями" римляне называли духов предков. "Генетика" — это "родовой", "относящийся к предкам". "Генерировать" — "порождать", родительный падеж — это калька с латинского "генетив". В общем, мысль ясна, надеюсь.